# Finding a PDF for X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So let's say I pick 4 balls out of a hat with no replacements. Let's say there's 3 black balls and 7 red balls. Let X denote the number of red balls I pick then what's P(X = 3 | X >= 2). I know what the formula is but I don't know how to find a PDF for X. Like what are the probabilities for choosing only 1 red ball or 2 red balls ect?

Comment: This thing should not have a pdf; it is not continuous. pmf and pdf are not interchangeable. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried finding all the probabilities like the probability of x being 1 or x being 2 all the way to x being 4. I've tried finding the probabilities for all those options but all the probabilities from 1-4 don't add up to 1 and I feel like they should.

Comment: @Chase Yes they should.  *What* do you think the probability of $X=k$ is?

Comment: Well that's what I want to know. I'm trying to figure out how to find this probability but I have no idea how to do it. I've tried multiplying .7 * .3 * .3 * .3 to try and get the probability that X = 1 but that doesn't work so I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I did multiply the numbers and I got the wrong answer. Am I multiplying the numbers wrong?

Comment: @Chase: That's the probability that the first ball is black, when selecting *with* replacement.  You want to do it without replacement, and in any order.

Comment: Chase, you are using the formula for picking balls with replacement. The question states that the picking is to be done without replacement.

Answer (score 0):

> I know what the formula is but I don't know how to find a PDF for X.

By this I presume you mean that you know the formula for Conditional Probability, and possibly how to use Complements.

BTW: You actually need to find the *probability mass function*, **pmf**, for the variable.

Then all that is left is to recognise that you have a *hypergeometric* distributed random variable, *or* to work out from first principles the probability of selecting, $k$ of $7$ red *and* $4-k$ of $3$ black balls when selecting, any $4$ of all $10$ balls, without bias nor repetition.

$\Box\!\!\!\!\raise{0.25ex}\Box~$ What have tried?

Comment: I have no idea what pmf is. I've learned about pdf and conditional tables which are similar to pdf tables. What I simply do not understand is how do I find the probabilities of choosing 1 red ball or what is the probability of choosing 2 red balls or what is the probability of choosing 3 red balls or what is the probability of choosing 4 red balls? So if I choose 1 red ball then the rest are black balls and there are 3 black balls and 7 red balls so what is the probability of that happening?

Comment: @Chase A *probability mass functions* is the probability measure for discrete random variables; which can often be expressed in tableau form.  A *probability density function* is the measure used with smoothly continuous random variables; which can't.  Ergo: It sounds like what you know is **pmf** and you are using the wrong term. (You *may* be confused by *Cumulative Distribution Function*, CDF, where the "D" stands for something else).

Comment: @Chase There are $^7{\rm C}_1$ ways to select 1 from 7 red balls, $^3{\rm C}_3$ ways to select 3 from 3 black balls, and $^{10}{\rm C}_4$ ways to select any 4 from all 10 balls.  Put it together.

Comment: I'm looking at my notes right now and I see the words probability distribution for X. It's a table for the random variable X where P(X = k) for each discrete random variable. There's also a cdf which is the cumulative distribution for X which is all the probabilties where P(X <= k).

Comment: @Chase Yes, all random variables have a probability distribution.  However, the *function* $~p_X(x)~=~\mathsf P(X=k)~$, used with *discrete* distributions, is called a *probability mass function*, **pmf**, to distinguish it from the *probability density function*, **pdf**, used with  *continuous random variables*.  It just appears that you haven't encountered those yet; but you *shall* later.

Comment: Anyway I'm still very confused over how this question works. i know how the table would be structured but I have no idea how to actually find the actual probabilities for each value of X. To start, what is the probability that you only choose 1 red ball?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you pick x red balls.
Then you will be picking 4-x black balls.

There are $\binom{10}{4}$ ways to pick 4 balls without replacement from 10 balls.

There are $\binom{7}{x}$ ways to pick x red balls without replacement from 7 red balls.

There are $\binom{3}{4-x}$ ways to pick 4-x black balls without replacement from 3 black balls.

So the PMF (i.e. the "formula") is:

$$P(X = x) = \frac{\binom{7}{x}\binom{3}{4-x}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$